# Connect to remote database on amazon server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I am working on Laravel5.4 application and it has its own database. for some business I need to connect to another remote database on amazon server to read some data and insert also some data but all tries failed. I tried:

**.env.php:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

DB_EXT_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_EXT_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx
DB_EXT_PORT=3306
DB_EXT_DATABASE=db2
DB_EXT_USERNAME=root
DB_EXT_PASSWORD=root
```

**Config/database.php:**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    //External Database Credentials
    'ext_mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_EXT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_EXT_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_EXT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_EXT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_EXT_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_EXT_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

The I try in my controller:

```
$users = DB::connection('ext_mysql')->table('users')->get();
return $users;
```

But, the connection on browser is take too long and finally gives `'Connection time out'`

Can anybody help ?

Comment: I suppose the first question to ask is, Can you connect to the server using mysql client  eg. adminer, navicat, mysql workbench? Chances are your remote mysql server is not accepting remote connections.

Comment: Sounds like the remote MySQL DB may be preventing your IP from connecting to it. Make sure remote MySQL access is allowed on the external DB.

Comment: How can I check remote MySQL access is allowed on the external DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to connect to another remote database on amazon server to read
>   some data

If your database resides in remote machine then, you need to use `hostname` or ip address of remote machine.

I'm not aware of `env` method, but I think, you need to change

```
'host' => env('DB_EXT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
```

to

```
'host' => env('DB_EXT_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'),
```

`'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'` would be ip address of remote machine.

Comment: yes, I did and it is found in .env file, what you can see in hot 127.0.01 is the default IP, but it reads from .env.  MySQL DB may be preventing your IP from connecting to it as a comment of @Niraj

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your external database in your .env file as with prefix as DB_EXT_ and you are trying to access in config/database.php files as DB_SRD.

Change your **config/database.php** file

```
'ext_mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_EXT_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_EXT_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_EXT_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_EXT_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_EXT_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_EXT_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
]
```

Also check that your remote database supports connection from external IP address.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry for EXT, I updated my question and it is not working at all. How can I check that remote database supports connection from external IP address?

Comment: Which remote db are you using? Is it RDS?

Comment: It is a default database setup on amazon.

Comment: You can log in to AWS console, goto RDS https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home  and check settings of your DB instance. Look for and option "Public accessibility" and set it to Yes.